# What is $ (3 + w + 2w^2)^4 $ ? where $w$ is cube roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

My progress:

    We know that **1 + w + w<sup>2</sup> = 0**, so

> (3 -1 - w<sup>2</sup> + 2w<sup>2</sup>)<sup>4</sup>
>   
> or, (2+ w<sup>2</sup>)<sup>4</sup>

How can I progress after this.
Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?  $3+w+2w^2$ or $(3+w+2w^2)^4$?

Comment: Please consider using MathJax notation in the future to make your questions more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

To calculate $(2+w^2)^4$, I would suggested squaring $2+w^2$, simplifying, and squaring the result.

(To simplify, remember that $w^4=w$ and $w^2+w+1=0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Take instead

$$(3+w+2(-1-w))^4=(1-w)^4=1-4w+6w^2-4w^3+w^4=$$

$$=1-4w+6w^2-4+w=1-4w+6(-1-w)-4+w= $$

$$= -9-9w$$

up to you...

Answer (score 0):

We start from $(3+w+2w^2)^4$

As you already mentioned, we know $1+w+w^2 = 0$, so we reduce the starting expression to $(2+w^2)^4$. WIth further substitution, since $w^2=-1-w$, we get:

$(2+w^2)^4 = (2-1-w)^4=(1-w)^4 = 1-4w+6w^2-4w^3+w^4$. Can you continue simplyfying from there?